# Android search music

Tags: java, android

I search about read song in android and I see a code from you:

```
private static ArrayList<SongModel> LoadSongsFromCard() {
    ArrayList<SongModel> songs = new ArrayList<SongModel>();

    // Filter only mp3s, only those marked by the MediaStore to be music and longer than 1 minute
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0"
            + " AND " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE + "= 'audio/mpeg'"
            + " AND " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + " > 60000";

    final String[] projection = new String[] {
        MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,             //0
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,           //1
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,          //2
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,            //3
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME
    };

    final String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE
            + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    Cursor cursor = null;

    try {
        // the uri of the table that we want to query
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI; //getContentUriForPath("");
        // query the db
        cursor = _context.getContentResolver().query(uri,
                projection, selection, null, sortOrder);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();                       
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) { 
                //if (cursor.getString(3).contains("AwesomePlaylists")) {
                    SongModel GSC = new SongModel();
                    GSC.ID = cursor.getLong(0);
                    GSC.songTitle = cursor.getString(1);
                    GSC.songArtist = cursor.getString(2);
                    GSC.path = cursor.getString(3);

                    // This code assumes genre is stored in the first letter of the song file name
                    String genreCodeString = cursor.getString(4).substring(0, 1);
                    if (!genreCodeString.isEmpty()) {
                        try {
                            GSC.genre = Short.parseShort(genreCodeString);
                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                            Random r = new Random();
                            GSC.genre = (short) r.nextInt(4);
                        } finally {
                            songs.add(GSC);
                        }
                    }
                //}
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    return songs;
}
```

I'm really learning to program for Android, and modify your code for what I needed , but I have trouble understanding when you assign cursor

```
cursor = _context.getContentResolver () query ( uri , projection , selection , null, sortOrder ) . ;
```

Part of `_context` not understand you kindly explain it please.

Answer (score 0):

If your class extends activity you can use `this` for _context. If not, you need to pass the context from your activity. The first case mentioned would look like this:

```
// query the db
cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, null, sortOrder);
```

__

[What is Context in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)